# What type of connector is this, and how do I remove it?

Tags: electrical, wiring, connectors

Home DIYer here.

What type of connector is this, and how do I remove it?

[image: connector]

Comment: I've only ever seen these used on ground wires.  I'm not sure that is allowed on neutral.  I guess that was all wrapped in electrical tape?

Comment: I drove an awl into the connector between the wires.  That loosened it enough to let me pull out the wires one by one.

Comment: Your home was wired 50 or more years ago ?

Comment: Does the other side look like there's a cut in the middle? If so, it may be folded and probably easier to remove starting on that side.

Answer (score 24):

That right there is a crimp connector.  Few ways to remove one, mostly you want to avoid damaging wire and losing length.  It's a compressed ring.

First thing I'd try is side cutters.  Cut between the wires and once one side of the ring is removed you should be able to bend it out of the way.  That one looks particularly easy to cut this way.

If side cutters don't work, I'd evaluate whether I can afford to lose wire length.  If it's not an issue, cut the wires where they enter the crimp.  If it is an issue, I'd use a rotary tool with a thin disc to make the necessary cuts with minimal risk.  If you put any significant gouge in the copper, it should be cut back to the gouge so you're only using good wire.

Comment: Do you think it looks like lead (Pb)? If so, squishing it one way and then the other repeatedly with a pair of pliers will make it fall to pieces.

Comment: @AndrewMorton lead would seem too weak for the task

Comment: @AndrewMorton that said, many types can be broken with fatigue.

Comment: True, and copper is no exception.